# Why doesn't Harry get in trouble for casting 'Lumos' in the third Harry Potter book?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

Why doesn't Harry get in trouble for casting Lumos (and thereby breaking The Decree for the Restriction of Underage Wizardry) AFTER he flees the Dursley's house when he first sees Sirius in his animagi form right before The Knight Bus arrives?
(It happens on page 33, in Chapter 3 of my copy of the Prisoner of Azkaban)

Is this maybe pardoned by Fudge due to the possibility that Voldemort or Sirius might have attacked Harry? At the bottom of page 43, Fudge implies that he had thought something bad had happened to Harry.

Any Theories?

Comment: I saw that you originally posted on the other question, but I'm not sure why you think the answers would be any different whether he used *lumos* or *lumos maxima*.

Answer (score 1):

From Chapter Three of Prisoner of Azkaban:

> "I broke the Law!" Harry said.  "The Decree for the Restriction of Underage Wizardry!"
>
> "Oh, my dear boy, we're not going to punish you for a little thing like that!...We don't send people to Azkaban just for blowing up their aunts!"

I don't think that if Fudge wouldn't punish Harry for blowing up his Aunt, he would punish him for a minor charm like *Lumos*.